# I have about 800 separate YQL queries that need processing and it's taking a long time

Tags: php, sql, database, message-queue, yql

Are there tips to queue this or pause each query so that YQL can return the results before moving on to the next query. I am programming this in PHP and each query takes about 4 seconds. I am just using a "while loop" to go through my array of 800 queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you sending the YQL request in PHP? In a lot of other languages that I have used these CURL-like requests will be synchronous anyways, so why is there the need to pause actively?

Also in terms of speeding things up, did you look at YQL's query.multi to parallelize queries? Example for YQL console. [Try it](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20query.multi%20where%20queries=%22show%20tables;select%20%2a%20from%20feed%20where%20url=%27http://www.javarants.com/rss%27%22&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)

```
select * from query.multi where queries="show tables;select * from feed where url='http://www.javarants.com/rss'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick suggestion for your problem. I don't know why you are creating so much querys, but could you use Javascripts setTimeout in client side. If I remember right YQL querys can be done with javascript. But if you need that data in server side then this isn't right solution.

Comment: I am using YQL to parse data from 800 websites then extracting some information from each. I could use "sleep(5)" in PHP to pause between each query.